# Get values of a textbox changed by javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

strange bug:

i have an ajax datepicker added to a text box of my form.

i submit the form.. and I could receive all values excepting those of the datepicker checkboxes.

why is the .Text property empty of this elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your TextBox disabled for user input, so that it might only be changed by javascript, by the datepicker?

The problem in that case, is that .NET "knows" that the control is disabled, and just assumes that the value cannot, then, have changed since it was rendered. So .NET will use the ViewStated value immediately, without checking the POST data.

There are two solutions to this:

1. Don't render the TextBox as disabled, but disable it with the datepicker script
2. Instead of relying on the TextBox's `Text` property, check `Request.Form[myTextBox.ClientID]`

Comment: yes it's disabled by javascript :) but it needs to. i try your second solution

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing SelectedDate instead of Text.

Comment: it's a textbox which hasn't a SelectedDate property :(

Comment: Oh sorry, I was referring to a DatePicker control.